# How to substitute all the paths in the envs to other path?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I have fallowing situation:

All my software is installed on the `/home/daniel/*` path and internally refers to it.
Nevertheless, when I use a network drive, the reference changes to `/home/foo/daniel` and I can't use my software anymore.

Is there a way to change the path of the go, e.g. trough invoking some program or changing some env variable ? Or I have to have two sets of programs ?

Comment: This is unclear. (1) What do you mean by “the `/home/daniel/*` path”? Do you mean “the `/home/daniel` path”? Or “various `/home/daniel/thing` directories”? (2) Tell us something about “your software”. Is it scripts? (shell? Perl? etc.) or compiled programs (like C++ or Java)? (3) How does your software refer to your directory? (4) Have you done `echo "$HOME"` and then run it both ways? (5) I guess that your `/home/daniel` directory exists on some computer. And then, when you login elsewhere, you have to connect to *your* computer over the net. Can you look at the name of the host you’re on?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your software *refers* to the path internally.

If it's only via environment variables, you can do something like:

```
eval "$(export -p | sed 's|/home/daniel|/home/foo/daniel|g')"
```

To change all the `/home/daniel`s to `/home/foo/daniel` in their value.

Adding `/home/foo/daniel/lib` (or wherever you have shared libraries installed) to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` may help your programs to find them. But if some of your software are hardcoded to look for conf files in `/home/daniel/etc`, or some datafile in `/home/daniel/share`, there's no equivalent standard environment variable that can be set to override it.

If you can't add a `/home/daniel` -> `../foo/daniel` symlink or can't create chroots or user mount namespaces to work around the problem, you may be better of recompiling your software with a `--prefix=/var/tmp/daniel` for instance, so you know you can always symlink that to wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll assume that you are talking about shell scripts. 
Try using the fact that the name of the script is available as `$0`. 
Unfortunately, this can be something like `./myprog`,
which doesn’t help,
so use `realpath` (or equivalent) to get the full pathname.

As far as I can tell from your question, this should always work. 
But, in case it’s not good enough, try using `$PWD` as a fallback. 
The following code ‘should’ do the job:

```
getdir()
{
    case "$1" in
      (*/daniel/*)
            my_dir=$(printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed 's|/daniel/.*|/daniel|'
            return 0
      (*)
            return 1
    esac
}

getdir $(realpath "$0")  ||  getdir "$PWD"  ||  { echo "I dunno."; exit 1; }
```

So, if your script currently says something like

```
date >> /home/daniel/log
```

you would change it to

```
date >> "$my_dir"/log
```

I just stumbled across [How can I get the source directory
of a Bash script from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/3960947),
which has 72 answers, some of which are variations on the above.